# Sending an async email without await from a .Net core web service

Tags: entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webservice .Net core2 that has certain methods that send an email. I have it working fine using `smtpclient.sendemailasync`.

```
    public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(MailMessage email)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailFrom)) email.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            using (SmtpClient client = getSMTPClientInstance())
            {
                await client.SendMailAsync(email);

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Error sending email in EmailService.SendEmailAsync");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The only issue is that some SMTP servers take a little too long to respond. I want to set up the email, queue it and return without waiting for the result.

Just using an unawaited async is out for 2 reasons;

1. It is not reliable to continue a method outside a request context in asp
2. I need access to the database context of my entity framework to write a log

I have to allow for external or internal SMTP (my client specifies), so a collection folder is not a possibility - at least not without a service that manages it.

How could I achieve this? Do I need to write a service that manages this? If so, how would I do that inside my .Net Core App, keeping in mind that the service also needs to access the EF context to write a log

**UPDATE**

There is plumbing available in .NetCore DI especially for this. Refer to my additional answer below. Use IServiceScopeFactory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `RegisterAsyncTask` method on the Page object. That will signal the ASP.NET runtime you want to make sure these are finished before terminating the request context:

Example:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadSomeData));
}

public async Task LoadSomeData()
{

    var clientcontacts = Client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("api/contacts");
    var clienttemperature = Client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("api/temperature");
    var clientlocation = Client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("api/location");

    await Task.WhenAll(clientcontacts, clienttemperature, clientlocation);

    var contacts = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(await clientcontacts);
    var location = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await clientlocation);
    var temperature = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await clienttemperature);

    listcontacts.DataSource = contacts;
    listcontacts.DataBind();
    Temparature.Text = temperature;
    Location.Text = location;
}
```

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Answer (score 2):

So, while I have marked an answer, there are a couple of options that are better solutions for my specific example. First is the option to use a library like hangfire to schedule tasks - although that is not technically an answer to the question.

The better solution in .net core is to use IServiceScopeFactory

With IServiceScopeFactory you can rescope a task so it doesnt go out of scope when the request is complete. I did the following directly in a controller (I later moved to using the hangfire approach, but this works). As you can see, the async task is fired off in a new unawaited thread while the controller code continues.

```
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApprovalService>();
                await service.sendResponseEmailAsync(approvalInfo.ApprovalId, userID, approvalInfo.emailTo, approvalInfo.ccTo);
            }
        });
```